# Installing packages into ubuntu14.04 docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, init, apt-get

I currently have similar images being built for virtualbox and digital ocean for dev and production (they're using packer and ansible to build). They're using Ubuntu 14.04.

I've created a docker version from the same scripts without any issue. This is going to be for a Gitlab CI environment.

When I come to install packages inside a container I get an error. Potentially to do with broken init systems? Something not running?

My initial command is `/sbin/init` and I've tried with and without phusion/base-image.

The error is `msg: '/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef" -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold"   install 'docker-engine'' failed: invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/cgroup-lite not found.
dpkg: error processing package cgroup-lite (--configure):`

*(Yes, this is going to be a monolithic container rather than single-process and yes, I'm running docker from inside it - I'll be sharing `docker.sock` to make this work.)*

Comment: you may found [this issue comment](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20698#issuecomment-192606903) useful. also check out these issue threads ([1](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8791), and [2](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2990)) on the docker github repo.

Comment: @EliranMalka Thanks for the links. These issues seem similar but I think my issue might be more a system level config one than a docker dependency issue. Unless I've misunderstood?

Comment: i really don't know enough about docker to answer. but the logical assumption (due the above error) is that docker expects cgroup-lite to be installed before it is installed. try to install it via apt-get before loading docker. (also, people said that this is a problem with version 14.x of ubuntu due apt sources list changes - you could try another (major) version for a quick a/b test)

Comment: @EliranMalka I've tracked it down a bit further and `cgroup-lite` is installed, but it fails when being configured as an init script is not correctly copied in place.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had a look at the code for `invoke-rd.d` and found this relevant snippet.

```
# If we're running on upstart and there's an upstart job of this name, do
# the rest with upstart instead of calling the init script.
if which initctl >/dev/null && initctl version | grep -q upstart \
   && [ -e "$UPSTARTDIR/${INITSCRIPTID}.conf" ]
then
    is_upstart=1
elif test ! -f "${INITDPREFIX}${INITSCRIPTID}" ; then
    ## Verifies if the given initscript ID is known
    ## For sysvinit, this error is critical
    printerror unknown initscript, ${INITDPREFIX}${INITSCRIPTID} not found.
    if [ ! -e "$UPSTARTDIR/${INITSCRIPTID}.conf" ]; then
        # If the init script doesn't exist, but the upstart job does, we
        # defer the error exit; we might be running in a chroot and
        # policy-rc.d might say not to start the job anyway, in which case
        # we don't want to exit non-zero.
        exit 100
    fi
fi
```

A combination of docker replacing the init system, the inability to use upstart in an ubuntu docker container and the ubuntu package for cgroup-lite being built for upstart meant `dpkg --configure` was failing as the service couldn't be started.